# How to make members of an Array into an actor and add them to stage?

Tags: libgdx, animation, scene2d, android-studio

I have an animation (enemies) that I would like to add multiple times on the screen. From what I know, I can save memory and framerate-per-second by using one animating image and make an arraylist of it wherein each member is turned to an actor and added multiple times to the stage. I have searched similar problems like this but the answers were really not that helpful. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my code:

EnemyAnimation class:

```
    public class EnemyAnimation extends Actor{

    Ninja app;
    LevelOneScreen levelOneScreen;

    private Animation animation;
    private static final int  FRAME_COLS_WALK = 10;
    private static final int  FRAME_ROWS_WALK= 1;
    public TextureRegion   currentFrame;
    private float stateTime = 0f;

    public float Xpos;
    public float Ypos;
    public static final int fallSpeed = 250;
    public boolean remove = false;
    final float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();



    public animation(final Ninja app){
        this.app = app;
        Texture ninSprite = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ninSprite.jpg"), true);
        ninSprite.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest,Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest);



        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(ninSprite, (int) ninSprite.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int) ninSprite.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
        TextureRegion[] ninTexRegion = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
        int index = 0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                ninTexRegion[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }

        animation = new Animation(0.044f,ninTexRegion);
        currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

    }

    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        final float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        stateTime += delta;

        TextureRegion currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);


        batch.draw(currentFrame,Xpos,Ypos,getWidth(),getHeight());

    }
}
```

LevelOneScreen class:

```
public class LevelOneScreen implements Screen {

    public Ninja app;
    private Stage stage;
    private Stage stageNinja;
    public EnemyAnimation enemyAnimation;
    private Image ninImage;
    private Image levelOneImage;
    private float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    public ArrayList<EnemyAnimation> enemyAnimate;


    public LevelOneScreen(final Ninja app){
        this.app = app;
        this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth, app.screenHeight, app.camera));
        this.stageNinja = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth, app.screenHeight, app.camera));
        enemyAnimate = new ArrayList<EnemyAnimation>();
        enemyAnimation = new EnemyAnimation(app);
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

        InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stageNinja);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);




        levelOneBackground();
        enemy();
    }


    public void enemy(){


        stageNinja.addActor(enemyAnimate);


       /* 

         From here I cannot add the Arraylist enemyAnimate to the 
         stage and I received some errors. I would like to add elements to
         enemyAnimate and make each added elements into actors with 
         different positions to be added to the stage.

        */


    }





    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        update(delta);

    }



    public void update(float deltaTime){

        stage.draw();
        stageNinja.draw();

        stage.act(deltaTime);
        stageNinja.act(deltaTime);

    }
```

Update to my code:

I now use Array of libgdx but it still won't show the enemies on stage without an indexOutOfBounds error. Here's the code:

```
public class LevelOneScreen implements Screen {

    public Ninja app;
    private Stage stage;
    private Stage stageNinja;
    public EnemyAnimation enemyAnimation;
    private Image ninImage;
    private Image levelOneImage;
    private float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    public Array<EnemyAnimation> enemyAnimate;


    public LevelOneScreen(final Ninja app){
        this.app = app;
        this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth, app.screenHeight, app.camera));
        this.stageNinja = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth, app.screenHeight, app.camera));
        enemyAnimate = new Array<EnemyAnimation>();
        enemyAnimate.add(new EnemyAnimation(app));
        enemyAnimation = new EnemyAnimation(app);
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

        InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stageNinja);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);




        levelOneBackground();
        enemyAct1();
        //  ......
        enemyAct4();
    }


        public void enemyAct1(){

      for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){enemyAnimate.add(new EnemyAnimation(app));}

    enemyAnimate.get(1).setPosition(app.screenWidth*0.1f,app.screenHeight);
    stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(1));
    float enemyTimeDrop1 = (app.screenHeight/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(1).addAction(moveTo(app.screenWidth*0.1f,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop1));


    enemyAnimate.get(2).setPosition(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth,app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight);
       stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(2));
    float enemyHeight2 = app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight;
    float enemyTimeDrop2 = (enemyHeight2/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(2).addAction(moveTo(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop2));


    enemyAnimate.get(3).setPosition(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*2f,app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*2f);
        stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(3));
    float enemyHeight3 = app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*2f;
    float enemyTimeDrop3 = (enemyHeight3/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(3).addAction(moveTo(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*2f,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop3));


    enemyAnimate.get(4).setPosition(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*3f,app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*3f);
        stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(4));
    float enemyHeight4 = app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*3f;
    float enemyTimeDrop4 = (enemyHeight4/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(4).addAction(moveTo(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*3f,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop4));


    enemyAnimate.get(5).setPosition(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*4f,app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*4f);
        stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(5));
    float enemyHeight5 = app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*4f);
    float enemyTimeDrop5 = (enemyHeight5/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(5).addAction(moveTo(app.screenWidth*0.1f+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*4f,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop5));


}
```

enemyAct1() is drawn but enemyAct4() is not and returns an indexOutOfBoundsError : index can't be >= size: 21 >= 17. Here's enemyAct4():

```
public void enemyAct4(){
    for(int i = 20; i < 30; i++){
        enemyAnimate.add(new EnemyAnimation(app));
    }


    enemyAnimate.get(21).setPosition(app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2,app.screenHeight);
        stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(21));
    float enemyTimeDrop1 = 4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(21).addAction(moveTo(app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop1));



    enemyAnimate.get(22).setPosition((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth,(app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight));
    stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(22));
    float enemyHeight22 = (app.screenHeight+enemyAnimation.enemyHeight);
    float enemyTimeDrop22 = (enemyHeight22/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(22).addAction(moveTo((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)+enemyAnimation.enemyWidth,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop22));


    enemyAnimate.get(23).setPosition((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth,app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight));
    stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(23));
    float enemyHeight23 = app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight);
    float enemyTimeDrop23 = (enemyHeight23 /app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(23).addAction(moveTo((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth,enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop23));


    enemyAnimate.get(24).setPosition((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)+(enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*2f),app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*2f));
       stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(24));
    float enemyHeight24 = app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*2f);
    float enemyTimeDrop24 = (enemyHeight24/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(24).addAction(moveTo((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)+(enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*2f),enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop24));


    enemyAnimate.get(25).setPosition((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)-(enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*2f),app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*2f));
        stageEnemy.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(25));
    float enemyHeight25 = app.screenHeight+(enemyAnimation.enemyHeight*2f);
    float enemyTimeDrop25 = (enemyHeight25/app.screenHeight)*4.85f ;
    enemyAnimate.get(25).addAction(moveTo((app.screenWidth/2-enemyAnimation.enemyWidth/2)-(enemyAnimation.enemyWidth*2f),enemyDestination,enemyTimeDrop25));

}






    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        update(delta);

    }



    public void update(float deltaTime){

        stage.draw();
        stageNinja.draw();

        stage.act(deltaTime);
        stageNinja.act(deltaTime);

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a separate object for every level

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/why-does-the-texture-from-assetmanager-displays-black-rectangles-only-libgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load a new `Texture` in each `EnemyAnimation` which loads alot of memory.

For example if it's a **500x500** image, it has **250,000 pixels**. One pixel has **3 bytes** so it's **750000 bytes** -> **0.71 MB**. One enemy takes **1MB of `RAM`**. Remember that I've mentioned 500x500 image, your is probably bigger.

It's unacceptable, you should reuse the image on all enemies.

Use `AssetLoader`/`AssetManager` as written here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

You should load your `ninSprite.jpg` with `AssetManager` and then in your `NinjaAnimate` class call

```
Texture tex = manager.get("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class);
```

Remember to use only one instance of your AssetManager and load them only once.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response. I want to know if it's a smart choice to use array of libgdx instead of arraylist and from there I will also use AssetManager.

Comment: To be super-professional you should use Object Pooling: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management

Also, you shouldn't use `Array` class from GDX. Use classic `ArrayList`

Comment: From what I have researched Array is better than ArrayList, or am I missing something?

Comment: You have to specify, doyou want to use a normal `array` like `Ninja[]` or the `Array` class?https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html

Comment: I want to use the array that will let me add elements beyond 17.

Comment: Ok so:
If you are sure that you have a constant number of elements, use a classic array[]
If you will add and remove ninjas (if they're dead or something) - you should use Array<> class, so yes, you should use the Array class.

Comment: I encountered a problem using assetmanager. The docs says that assetmanager shouldn't be static but when I get the texture from assetmanager an error says non-static manager cannot be accessed on static-context. Here's code: 
'Texture ninSprite = new Texture(NinjaAssets.manager.get("ninSprite.png",Texture.class));'

Comment: It may be static - no worries. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470539/libgdx-static-assetmanager

Comment: The enemies only show a black square on my screen. I tried checking for the name of the asset for any spelling/capitalization error and other possible causes but it still won't show. 'manager.load("ninSprite.png",Texture.class);'. But when i change "ninSprite.png" to "assets/ninSprite.png" it gives an error saying couldn't load dependencies of asset.

Comment: J, please create a new question for this. Here, on StackExchange forums we avoid answering questions in comments cause if someone would look for a similar problem - it'll be easier to look for a question. When you create a question - post a link here.

Comment: Spectre I've created my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/why-does-the-texture-from-assetmanager-displays-black-rectangles-only-libgdx

Answer (score 1):

An `EnemyAnimation` is an actor in itself, you do not need to *create an actor from the list of EnemyAnimation* as the title of your post suggests.

`EnemyAnimate` is NOT an actor, it is a `List` of actors, so the line

```
stageNinja.addActor(enemyAnimate);
```

should be replaced by

```
stageNinja.addActor(enemyAnimate.get(i)); // where i is an iterator you need to set to get the actor you want to get.
```

In the `LevelOneScreen` constructor you initialize an `EnemyAnimation` object but you never add it to the List.

You can change the line

```
enemyAnimation = new EnemyAnimation(app);
```

to

```
enemyAnimate.add(new EnemyAnimation(app));
```

and you can get rid of the enemyAnimation variable as it will not be used anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried using your solution and it worked but only to a limited number of 17 elements inside the arraylist. I get an error when I set a for loop with i being equal to more than 17, the error says indexOutOfBounds and that it should only be 17 max.

Comment: I also tried replacing ArrayList with Array of libgdx and the indexoutofbounds error is still there.

Comment: IndexOutOfBound is because the indexes start at 0 and go to `size - 1`. For example if you have a 17 elements array, you need to call `myArray[16]` to access last element, `myArray[17]` will cause an IndexOutOfBound

Comment: How can I set the size of an array? I will be using maybe 500 elements. When I make a for loop like this it gives an outofbounds error and says max is 17 when I don't even set the size of the array to 17. Here's the for loop:

for(i = 20 ; i < 30; i++){} ==> gives an error saying 20>17

Comment: An ArrayList has **no fixed size**. If you have an IndexOutOfBound exception it means you have added only 17 elements in your list, and you are trying to access the 20th, that's all. You can check the size of your list by doing `enemyAnimate.size()`

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/why-does-the-texture-from-assetmanager-displays-black-rectangles-only-libgdx

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/how-to-refresh-dependencies-after-adding-freetype-extension-in-android-project

Comment: Guys can you visit my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971321/how-to-restart-screen-in-libgdx-using-init-methods